# How to use One Django a modelform view to create a new header detail entry in the database

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a header and a detail table with each its own models defined.
The header table would for instance be a customers name, and the detail, it's address.
But to make it simple, in this testcase is, the header table is called mv_movie and only contains the auto incrementing primary key(uid), and a create date.
The detail table called mvd_detail, contains a auto incrementing primary key(uid), the movie name and an image field for the movie poster.
The idea is is to use one form and one view with the detail model, and create a a new movie entry by save the current date in the header table, then saving the name and image to the detail table.

It is not problem saving the date in the header table and returning the new uid(pk).

The problem is saving the movie name and the poster image because the detail model has a foreign key field referencing the header table that may not be null.

Models below.

```
class MvMovie(models.Model):
    mv_uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    mv_create_date = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mv_movie'


class MvdDetail(models.Model):
        mvd_uid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        mvd_mv_uid = models.ForeignKey(MvMovie, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='mvd_mv_uid')
        mvd_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        mvd_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='main/covers')

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'mvd_detail'
```

Forms below.

```
class NewMovie(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MvdDetail
        fields = [# 'mvd_mv_uid',
                  'mvd_name',
                  'mvd_image']

        labels = {
            'mvd_name': 'Movie Name',
            'mvd_image': 'Poster'
        }

        widgets = {
            # 'mvd_mv_uid': forms.HiddenInput,
            'mvd_name': forms.TextInput(),
            'mvd_image': forms.ClearableFileInput()
        }
```

View below.

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from main.forms import NewMovie
from main.models import MvMovie, MvdDetail
from datetime import datetime as dt


def movie_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewMovie(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            mv = MvMovie(mv_create_date=dt.now())
            mv.save()
            k = mv.pk
            # THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
            form.save()
        return redirect(movie_list)
    else:
        form = NewMovie()
        return render(request, 'main/movie_new.html', {"form": form})
```

In the form mvd_mv_uid is commented out because if I use it, form.is_valid() will fail.
In the view I have indicated where the problem is.

The request.POST and request.FILES returns the following

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['opY6MVh7cM60UAuZmEimDsPlcd7xRFzpra9RsoITs5KEwatpQz6KG1rGVDPZfXu4'], 'mvd_name': ['Some Movie Name']}>
<MultiValueDict: {'mvd_image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: black-panther-web.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

How do I get that pk value in the QueryDict to save it, or is there another approach?

By the way, the reason behind why I want to do it like this is to use the never update(valid data), never delete, only insert approach.
In other words end the last record, with a field that does not exist in this example, but will, and insert new, "updated", record with an open(last record) indicator.

Help would be highly appreciated.